# NSAttributedString not returning expected value

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to create text like: *"**bill** started following you."* and make the username semibold. I tried this but doing .string gives me a weird long string. How can I fix it?

```
        //let nUsername = username
    let fontU = UIFont(name: "SFCompactDisplay-Semibold", size: 15)
    let fontN = UIFont(name: "SFCompactDisplay-Regular", size: 15)

    let usernameAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: fontU]
    let notifAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: fontN]

    let firstString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: username, attributes: usernameAttributes)
    let secondString = NSAttributedString(string: " started following you.", attributes: notifAttributes)

    firstString.append(firstString)
    firstString.append(secondString)

    //notifInfoLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 77, y: 15, width: 295, height: 18)
    notifInfoLabel.text = "\(firstString.string)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of:

```
firstString.append(firstString)
```

That duplicates the username.

And you are not using the final attributed string. Use:

```
notifInfoLabel.attributedText = firstString
```